# How can I put the first three words on each line into an arraylist?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

```
public class scripttest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("text.txt");
        script(file);
    }

    public static void script(File filename) {
        String line = null;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file named '" + filename + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to make a script function for my program, the script requires a file, which each command written out on each line to be carried out consecutively. How do I add the first three words on each line to an arraylist, which will then be used to interpret the commands for each line?

Comment: split the line using spaces and get the first three words?

Answer (score 0):

```
// considering you have line variable. myArrayList is ur list. 

String[] words = line.split(" ");
if(words.length() >= 3) {
   myArrayList.add(words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        script("text.txt");
    }

    private static void script(String filename) {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            stream.forEach(TestScript::executeLine);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void executeLine(String line) {
        System.out.println(line);

        String[] args = line.split(" ");
        executeCommand(Arrays.stream(args).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                Arrays.stream(args).skip(3).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private static void executeCommand(List<String> command, List<String> args) {
        System.out.println(command + ": " + args);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a stream of RegEx results, you can use [Pattern#splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-). As in: `Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(line).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList())`